# Floating block collapse

Tags: html, css, grid

I make grid system and i have encountered "strage" behaviour of block
for example

**HTML:**

```
<div class="l_row">
    <div class="l_cell"></div>
    <div class="l_cell"></div>
    <div class="l_cell"></div>
    <div class="l_cell"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.l_row {
    min-width: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 2rem auto;
}
.l_row:before, .l_row:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.l_row:after {
    clear: both;
}
.l_cell {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 15px;
    width: 25%;
}
.l_row .l_cell:last-child {
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

And if `.l_cell` have some content at least one symbol `1, a, &nbsp;` - works well, but if `.l_cell` is empty it collapses to `width:0` and ignoring `width` in `css`

Comment: hey @user2311920, you want vertically repeated lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout can be fixed with a few minor adjustments.

(1) If you add padding to `.l_cell`, this will increase the box width and the four `.l_cell` blocks with width 25% will not fit on a single line.  You can fix this by using `box-sizing: border-box` which will force `.l-cell` to keep the over width to 25% while also including the 20px right padding.

(2) The "zero collapse width" effect is due to the nature of the floats.  Since you did not specify a height or minimum height, any float without content will have zero height but with 25% width.  If you have a sequence of floats as in your example, the left edges of the floats will be positioned to the left as far as possible until they hit the right edge of a previous float.  If a float has zero height, it has no right edge, to it appears to have zero width.  If you add a `min-height` value, all the floats will position themselves as you expect.

```css
.l_row {
    min-width: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 2rem auto;
}
.l_row:before, .l_row:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.l_row:after {
    clear: both;
}
.l_cell {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 25%;
    min-height: 20px;
}
.l_cell:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: beige;   
}
.l_cell:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: lightblue;   
}
.l_row .l_cell:last-child {
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="l_row">
    <div class="l_cell">x1</div>
    <div class="l_cell"></div>
    <div class="l_cell">x3</div>
    <div class="l_cell"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanx. Border-box i use everywhere. It's default for me. And fro min-height - great Thaks/

Answer (score 0):

use `&nbsp` inside it to achieve what you are looking for.

**For instance,**

`<div class="l_cell">&nbsp;</div>`

This considers the div as a block with content.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Finded...
https://css-tricks.com/make-sure-columns-dont-collapse-horizontally/

```
.col {
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    min-height: 1px;
}
```